# A question about linear algebra, T is an linear transformation, than what can we learn from T * T?

Tags: linear-algebra

Another question:
Let $T : V → V$ be a linear transformation. Suppose
that $T^m = 0$ for some positive integer m. Show that $T^n = 0$, where
$n = dim_F V$
I have no idea for this exercise, Any one who can help? Thanks.

Comment: $T^{2}(x)=T(T(x)), T^{3}(x)=T(T(T(x)))$ etc.

Comment: thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

$T^m = 0$ indicates all the eigenvalues of T are 0. Then you can just apply Cayley–Hamilton theorem.

Comment: Teacher didn't mention the matrix representation of linear transformation,  so i want to utilize something what i had learn to prove it(linear transformation).   But Thanks your answer.